# capture video from file emgu cv 2.4.10

Tags: c#, opencv, video, emgucv

I am trying to create simple application using emgu cv 2.4.10 for reading video from file and processing its frame.
I have istalled emgu cv 2.4.10 and used followin code to capture video from file.

Capture from web camera works fine. but capture from file gives error.
I tried opening .Mp4,*.avi and .wmv files but got the error saying "Cannot capture video from <>"

i have created basic as

```
private Capture _capture;
_capture = new Capture(); 
openFileDialog1.Filter = "MP4|*.mp4";
openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    _capture = new Capture(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
    _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue in emgucv 2.4.10,

Installed emgucv 2.4.9 and the same sample of code worked perfectly.